# Класс для работы с однонаправленным связанным списком

Tags: java

Как работает однонаправленный связанный список?
Как именно вносяться данные в него?

```
package org.jazzteam;

import java.util.*;

public class List {

    class LinkedListDemo {
        public void main(String args[]) {
            // создаем лист
            LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
            // добавляем элементы
            ll.addLast("Z");
            ll.add("F");
            ll.add("B");
            ll.add("D");
            ll.add("E");
            ll.add("C");
            ll.addFirst("A");
            ll.add(1, "A2");
            System.out.println("Элементы листа: " + ll);
            // удаляем элементы
            ll.remove("F");
            ll.remove(2);
            System.out.println("лист после удаления элемента: " + ll);
            // удаляем первый и последний элемент
            ll.removeFirst();
            ll.removeLast();
            System.out
                    .println("лист после удаления первого и последнего элемента: "
                            + ll);
            // получаем и устанавливаем значения
            Object val = ll.get(2);
            ll.set(2, (String) val + " Changed");
            System.out.println("лист после изменений: " + ll);
        }
    }

}
```

Мне нужно написать класс для работы с однонаправленным связанным списком с добавлением узлов в конец списка. Гуглил Американские сайты, толком ничего не нашел. Готовый класс не разрешают использовать.

Comment: зачем тебе 2 класса тут?? поробуй просто внутренний использовать LinkedListDemo

Comment: вот тут (http://habrahabr.ru/post/127864/) описано как LinkedList работает

Answer (score 1):

Исходники LinkedList доступны же :)
Если кратко, то необходимо создать подкласс содержащий элементы списка
Что-то вроде

```
private static class Entry<E> {
    E element;
    Entry<E> next;
    Entry(E e, E next) {this.element = e; this.next = next}
}
```

В конструкторе списка создать текущий элемент
Entry<E> current = new Entry<E>(null, null);
Остальное понятно надеюсь

Comment: обьяснение к коду: в списке данные заворачиваются в класс-обертку, -  класс хранит данные и ссылку на следующий элемент (в случае двонаправленного списка и на предыдущий тоже)

Comment: Исходик я видел, но там как то слишком много чего непонятного.

Comment: @bald2b В конструкторе неправильный тип у `next`